# plugins de descuento de woocomerce con api

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Estoy creado una app movil donde consumo la api de woocomerce en wordpress pero los descuentos que trae no me sirven por lo que instale plugins como "Advanced Dynamic Pricing for WooCommerce" o "Woo Discount Rules" pero ambos al hacer la consulta api no me muestra el descuento, también necesito que se pueda ver el descuento en si para mostrar su nombre y descripción en la app
que plugins permiten esto o como puedo modificar el código para que se muestre en la api

Comment: Bienvenido al sito Andres!! te doy la bienvenida y te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. Es importante modifiques el formato de tu pregunta agregando lo que has tratado o investigado, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

try following for "Advanced Dynamic Pricing for WooCommerce"

> Woocommerce>Pricing Rules, tab "Settings", tab "System", mark 
>   "Apply pricing rules to backend order"

Comment: El idioma oficial de este sitio es el español.